Set compile time prefix for printable messages
I would like to create a function that prints to the command line with a set prefix that will never change at runtime, so I would like to set it at compile time. Something like:
print_sp(const char * msg)
{
  printf("%s%s", prefix, msg);
}

Is there a way I can do this using constexpr in c++? If possible to do it in C++11 it would be even better.
I am trying to avoid having a singleton class with a SetPrefix method here.

Use {fmt} or C++20 std::format instead of printf. C++23 gives std::print and std::println too. The easiest method would be to put prefix in format string itself. For compile time string constants, the best type is constexpr std::string_view. If using std::literals;, then constexpr auto str="value"sv; is clean syntax.

One simple way to do it would be with the C preprocessor:
#define MYPREFIX "myprefix"

void print_sp(const char * msg)
{
   printf(MYPREFIX "%s", msg);
}


I thought about doing this but I believe I would need to do #define followed by #include in all files and I was thinking about doing this only once per program somehow - the idea is to put this in a header that will be used by around ten different command line tools that have around 4 cpp files each.

@eri0o You can usually specify defines on the command line. Eg -DMYPREFIX=\"myprefix\" if compiling with g++. Turns the job into a problem for the build utility you use.

There should be exactly one function that writes to the console. Any other functions that write output should assemble their text without the prefix and then call the function that writes to the console with the prefix. Nobody else knows or cares about the prefix.
